# Is permutation-invariance of an objective a problem in convex optimization?

Tags: convex-analysis

I have difficulty understanding how permutation-invariance and convexity are related in an optimization problem.

Let $f(.)$ be a **convex function** defined on $d$-dimensional vectors.
Suppose, also that $f$ is **permutation-invariant**, i.e., if we permute elements of $x$, $f(x)$ remains fixed where $x$ is a $d$-dimensional vector. Also, we know that $f$ is not a constant function.

Convexity, ensures that any convex combination of a set of solutions is also a solution.
Permutation-invariance ensures that any permutation of a solution is also a solution.

**Do these two properties contradict each other?**

**When do these two properties contradict each other?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no contradiction here. $f$ can have the form

$$f(x_1, ... x_n) = \sum_{i=1}^n g(x_i)$$

where $g$ is a convex function of one variable, e.g. $g(x) = x$ or $g(x) = x^2$.